# Необходимо брать input из файла

Tags: python, xml

В xml файле есть строки, каждая строка это ID, есть API в питоне, через которое нужно отправить токены и получить результат (записав в файл).

API выглядит так:

```
token = "e277bc42a2d2df54feb153d6e79d66eb7f5daa50"
        dadata = Dadata(token)
        result = dadata.find_by_id("address", "1278fedb-846e-4d99-90b5-f3deae8c1059")
```

Вот вместо "1278fedb-846e-4d99-90b5-f3deae8c1059" нужно отправлять строку из XML.
При этом это должен быть цикл где значение меняется на следующее и цикл идет дальше.

Comment: что у вас не получается? код ваш где?

Comment: в том то и дело - даже не представляю с чего начать

Comment: начните с того, что попытайтесь открыть и прочесть xml-файл.